# Is it possible to perform transaction replication with columns in Microsoft Sql Server?

Tags: .net, sql-server

I know that it is possible for table to be an article for transaction replication, but is it possible for a column to be an article in transaction replication?

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking whether you can replicate just a subset of columns on a given take, the answer is 'yes'. The article is still the table, but you needn't replicate all the columns. Check out @vertical_partition parameter on so_addarticle.